# Passportjs local strategy is not running

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am developing a node.js app and have included the use of passportjs for authentication.

But for some reason the login is not firing the local strategy for some reason. I have followed the examples but still no joy. My code is below

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var mysql = require('mysql') ;
var app = express();
var connection = null;

var encrypt = require('./node_custom_libraries/encrypt');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = ?', [id], function(err, user)
    {
        done(err,user);

    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        console.log('local strategy called');
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ?', [username], function(err, results)
        {
            console.log(results);
            if (results.length == 0)
            {
                return done(null, false, false);
            }
            else
            {
                var comparePassword = encrypt.comparePassword(password, results[0].password, function(err,result)
                    {
                        if (err) { return done(err); }

                        console.log(result);
                        return done(null, result);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
));

// all environments

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8500);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));

    // app setup for authentication
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'ecoSecret' }));
    // Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
    // persistent login sessions (recommended).
    //app.use(flash());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {

    //Connect to MYSQL database local database - DEV
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'xxx',
        password : 'xxx',
        database : 'xxx',
        port : 'xxx'
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        // connected! (unless `err` is set)
        if (!err)
        {
            console.log('database connected');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(err.code); // 'ECONNREFUSED'
            console.log(err.fatal); // true
        }

    });
}

//Add REST calls here
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log('req user' + req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/admin/users',
        failureRedirect: '/' })

});
```

My login request fires which shows message in console but that's it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working.

basically by using angularjs I was posting a user type i.e.

```
user {username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx'}
```

But instead i specifically set the object to post the following structure:

```
{username: xxx, password: xxx}
```

Answer (score 0):

`passport.authenticate` returns a function which must be passed to Express. This would work:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('req user' + req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/admin/users',
        failureRedirect: '/' })(req, res, next);

});
```

Express allows you to pass multiple handlers for a single route, so you can also do:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/admin/users', failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log('req user', req.body);
    console.log('after auth', req.user);
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi the above still does not work. It's not hitting the Localstrategy implementation for some reason.

Comment: I am using Angularjs if that makes any difference? But the post request does pass the username and password in a user object